# AWS lambda function not terminating the thread

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, thread-safety

I have a written a java code to execute from AWS lambda function. In my usecase I want to write some generic logs before it lambda function terminates. To achieve that i have crated a new thread which monitor a RemainingTimeInMillis of lambda function. If it reaches some limit i will write some generic message.
Now my issue is even if i terminate a thread it is not terminating.

```
public class Lambda implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, String> {
public String handleRequests(Map<String, String> parameters, Context context) {
    LambdaTimeoutCheck thread = null;
    thread = new LambdaTimeoutCheck(context, "applicationName");
        thread.setName(threadname);
        thread.setStopTimeout(true);
        thread.start();

        /* remaining function logic  */
        System.out.println("Lambda function starts"+thread.isAlive());

        thread.shutdown();

        System.out.println("Lambda function ends"+thread.isAlive());
        return "success"
}



package com.pearson.autobahn.autobahnsdkheartbeat;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;

public class LambdaTimeoutCheck extends Thread {

    private Context context;

    private String applicationName;

    private boolean isStopTimeout;


    public LambdaTimeoutCheck(Context context, String applicationName) {
        this.context = context;
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        while (isStopTimeout()) {

            if (context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() <= 1000) {
                
                context.getLogger().log("Request ID: " + context.getAwsRequestId() + " " + applicationName
                        + " function execution about to Timeout");
                setStopTimeout(false);
            } 
            }

        }
    }

    
    public void shutdown() {

        this.setStopTimeout(false);

    }

    
    public boolean isStopTimeout() {
        return isStopTimeout;
    }


    public void setStopTimeout(boolean isStopTimeout) {
        this.isStopTimeout = isStopTimeout;
    }

}
```

thread.isAlive() is always coming as true, even if i shutdown a thread. Kindly anyone assist me how to comeout from this issue.

Comment: First, your thread `run` method is a busy poll - it will run as fast as it can with zero wait.  This means that there isn't as much CPU available for other things.  Next, you shutdown your thread and then instantly check if it's shutdown.  It may take a bit, especially with the busy poll loop you have in your thread.  This code really need to be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any Java program: if your main thread needs to wait for another thread to complete you should call `join()` on the child thread.